# How can I use the system information to locate 48 GB of photos?

Tags: macos

I’m new to this Mac and have a month of experience. I think I have deleted every single photo on my laptop, and emptied recently deleted, and I'm getting this from the storage part of About This Mac...

[image]

I'm a youtube and really need to import footage & can't as I have no storage...

Answer (score 1):

In another forum they suggested to use a tool like OmniDiskSweeper 
(it can be downloaded here: https://www.omnigroup.com/more/) 
that can show you where the files that take up the space in your disk are.

Start by using the "File|Size Home Folder" and then explore further in the other directories if the images are not there.

Comment: Note that the pictures may be in the photos.app and if you have deleted all the pictures there you also have to empty the trash within the photos.app to reclaim all your lost space.